# how to create dynamic url in collection and model using backbone

Tags: url, backbone.js

My collection and model like this:

```
detail_userid = 0;
detail_contactid = 0;
var ContactDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    urlRoot: URL_CONTACTS1+detail_userid+"/"+detail_contactid
});

var ContactDetailCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: ContactDetail,
    url: URL_CONTACTS1+detail_userid+"/"+detail_contactid
})
```

The entrance is:

```
ContactDetailManagePageModel.prototype.init = function(m,n){ 
    detail_userid = m;
    detail_contactid = n;
    var myContactDetails = new ContactDetailCollection();
    var contactDetailListView = new ContactDetailListView({
            collection: myContactDetails
        });     
    myContactDetails.fetch({reset:true});
}
```

But when it runs,the url is :`http://localhost:8080/ws/users/contacts/0/0`,it means that the assignment to detail_userid and detail_contactid  is unsuccessful,I don't know why.

Hope for your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are statically definining the urlRoot and url properties before you are running the init of the PageModel (not quite sure where you are getting m and n from though...)

Both url and urlRoot can be a function, so you can pass in options during instantiation and have them dynamically set on the model.

Simple example covering defining the collection and then creating one

```
var ContactDetailCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: ContactDetail,
    url: function(){
      return URL_CONTACTS1 + this.options.detail_userid + "/" + this.options.detail_contactid;
    }
});

var myContactDetails = new ContactDetailCollection({
  detail_userid: foo,
  detail_contactid: bar
});
```

As I mentioned, I'm not sure what your init function is doing, I'm guessing it's something custom from your app that I don't need to worry about.

I'm fairly sure the main thing to take away is to set url and urlRoot dynamically

Comment: I did as you said,but it said that 'this.options is undefined'

Comment: sorry have been on holiday.... i can see that you've accepted the answer. are you all set now?

Comment: In coffeescript, this looks like `...extends Backbone.Collection constructor: (@options) -> url: -> "URL_CONTACTS1/#{@options.detail_userid}/#{@options.detail_contactid}"`

Comment: That was probably the way to do in the past, but now it won't work anymore. @Paul T. Rawkeen answer bellow should be the accepted answer for today.

Answer (score 7):

I would fulfill the accepted answer with few remarks.

1. First parameter when initializing `Backbone.Collection` is **array of models**, then **options**. To create an empty collection with options you should do next

   `var c = new Backbone.Collection(null, {opt1: val1, opt2: val2});`
2. Actually, you can't access `this.options` in `url` function, bec. there are no options like in a model. What you can do, is assign required properties from options upon initialization.

---

```js
initialize: function (models, options) {
    // `parseInt()` is used for consistency that `id` is numeric, just to be sure
    this.detail_userid = parseInt(options.detail_userid);
    this.detail_contactid = parseInt(options.detail_contactid);
}
```

Later you can access them like this:

```
url: function() {
    return URL_CONTACTS1 + this.detail_userid + "/" + this.detail_contactid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the HATEOAS href from one model to fetch data of another model. It worked to simply set the url on the newly created collection instead of defining it right away in the constructor.

```js
var DailyMeasuresCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //url : set dynamically with collection.url = url
    model : DailyMeasuresModel,
    parse : function(data) {
        return data._embedded.dailyMeasures;
    }
});

var DailyMeasuresTopicListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...

    events : {
        'click .select-topic' : 'onClick'
    },

    onClick : function() {
        var topicMeasures = new DailyMeasuresCollection()

        topicMeasures.url = this.model.attributes._links.measures.href // <- here assign

        var topicMeasuresView = new DailyMeasuresListView({
            collection : topicMeasures
        });
        topicMeasures.fetch()
    }
});
```